Unexpected output from OpenAI Whisper
The first part is copy/pasted from the hugging face page https://huggingface.co/openai/whisper-large-v3
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForSpeechSeq2Seq, AutoProcessor, pipeline

 device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
    torch_dtype = torch.float16 if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.float32
    model_id = "openai/whisper-small"
    model = AutoModelForSpeechSeq2Seq.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch_dtype, low_cpu_mem_usage=True, use_safetensors=True)
    model.to(device)
    processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(model_id)
    pipe = pipeline(
        "automatic-speech-recognition",
        model=model,
        tokenizer=processor.tokenizer,
        feature_extractor=processor.feature_extractor,
        max_new_tokens=128,
        chunk_length_s=30,
        batch_size=16,
        return_timestamps=True,
        torch_dtype=torch_dtype,
        device=device,
    )

The second part extracts the audio stream from a youtube video.
from pytube import YouTube

video = YouTube(url=link)
audio_stream = video.streams.get_by_itag(140)
buffer = io.BytesIO()
audio_stream.stream_to_buffer(buffer)
buffer.seek(0)
audio_seg = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(buffer, format="mp4")

# is this the right conversion to a ```torch.array1``` ? 
array = np.frombuffer(buffer.getbuffer(), dtype=np.uint8)
transcript = pipe(array) 

Now, using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=um3YrKRfsr0 it the transcript should be (approximately) the alphabet, however, I get this
{'text': ' වවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවව ლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლ� I I ლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლ�', 'chunks': [{'timestamp': (None, None), 'text': ' වවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවවව ლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლ� I I ლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლლ�'}]}

Also, setting low_cpu_mem_usage to false speeds up the transcription and I'm not sure why?
I've tried using speech_recognition and it works find but I want to use whisper because it produces the timestamps automatically.
edit: I found out that changing array = np.frombuffer(buffer.getbuffer(), dtype=np.uint8) into array = np.array(audio_seg.get_array_of_samples()).astype(np.float32) fixes the problem but the output is still mostly incorrect, the output I'm getting for the same video is
text': ' J B C D E F D G H I J J K J H I J J L M N O P Q R S V U R S V U V U X Y Z X Y Z Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y', 'chunks': [{'timestamp': (0.0, 2.0), 'text': ' J'}, {'timestamp': (2.0, 4.0), 'text': ' B'}, {'timestamp': (4.0, 6.0), 'text': ' C'}, {'timestamp': (6.0, 8.0), 'text': ' D'}, {'timestamp': (8.0, 10.0), 'text': ' E'}, {'timestamp': (10.0, 12.0), 'text': ' F'}, {'timestamp': (12.0, 14.0), 'text': ' D'}, {'timestamp': (14.0, 16.0), 'text': ' G'}, {'timestamp': (16.0, 18.0), 'text': ' H'}, {'timestamp': (18.0, 20.0), 'text': ' I'}, {'timestamp': (20.0, 22.0), 'text': ' J'}, {'timestamp': (22.0, 24.0), 'text': ' J'}, {'timestamp': (24.0, 25.34), 'text': ' K J H I J'}, {'timestamp': (27.5, 28.0), 'text': ' J'}, {'timestamp': (30.16, 30.66), 'text': ' L'}, {'timestamp': (32.58, 33.08), 'text': ' M'}, {'timestamp': (35.2, 35.7), 'text': ' N'}, {'timestamp': (37.76, 38.26), 'text': ' O'}, {'timestamp': (40.28, 40.78), 'text': ' P'}, {'timestamp': (42.92, 43.42), 'text': ' Q'}, {'timestamp': (45.1, 46.1), 'text': ' R S V U R'}, {'timestamp': (47.76, 48.76), 'text': ' S'}, {'timestamp': (50.4, 51.4), 'text': ' V'}, {'timestamp': (53.0, 54.0), 'text': ' U'}, {'timestamp': (55.7, 56.7), 'text': ' V'}, {'timestamp': (58.4, 59.4), 'text': ' U'}, {'timestamp': (61.2, 62.2), 'text': ' X'}, {'timestamp': (63.9, 64.9), 'text': ' Y'}, {'timestamp': (66.0, 68.0), 'text': ' Z X Y Z Y'}, {'timestamp': (68.0, 70.0), 'text': ' Y'}, {'timestamp': (70.0, 72.0), 'text': ' Y'}, {'timestamp': (72.0, 74.0), 'text': ' Y'}, {'timestamp': (74.0, 76.0), 'text': ' Y'}, {'timestamp': (76.0, 78.0), 'text': ' Y'}, {'timestamp': (78.0, 80.0), 'text': ' Y'}, {'timestamp': (80.0, 82.0), 'text': ' Y'}, {'timestamp': (82.0, 84.0), 'text': ' Y'}, {'timestamp': (84.0, 86.0), 'text': ' Y'}, {'timestamp': (86.0, 88.0), 'text': ' Y'}]}
